# How can i have and or together?

Tags: php

Im wondering if i can do and/or together. I'm trying to make a code that checks if both variables are wrong or if only one of them is wrong and the other one is right then I want to show a message like: "one of the "variables" are wrong.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: if $variable isnt 1 and its supposed to be, thats what i mean by wrong.

Comment: Even though I answered, I still think you should know this.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tim Whites answer, if you don't want it nested, you could also use:

```
    if($a == false AND $b == false) { echo "Both variables are false"; }
    elseif($a == false OR $b == false) { echo "One variable is false"; }
```

Comment: Replace `== false` with `!= 1` if you want to check according to your comment on your question, @Sigve Alexander

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($a==false OR $b==false) {
   if($a==false AND $b==false) { echo "Both variables are false"; }
   else { echo "On of the variables is false"; }
}
```

Something like that will do.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use multiple `IF` statements, to check if 1 variable is wrong or both are wrong. Like:

```
if ($variable1==false && $variable2==false){

}
else{
if ($variable1==false || $variable2==false){

}
}
```